# Using the Stack Overflow site

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've been visitng Stack Overflow for a while, but I didn't get membership earlier. If I need clarity on an answer a user replied to in the topic (not essentially the last answer in sequenvce), how should I post to that specific answer?

I know there are edits done by the person answering, but with a line break some other users also add/ask to that specific answer. For example, I needed to check what does the user "nakedfanatic" mean when he says "concatenating two files", like how would an XPIF format file would be concatenated to a PDF file.

See [an answer to Stack Overflow question *How do I create a dynamic job ticket for Xerox printers?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051536/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-job-ticket-for-xerox-printers/15013209).

I am not sure how I do that and if it's in conformance with the procedures of Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Answer (score 4):

You should comment on the answer. However, that requires 50+ reputation. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Answer (score 4):

Earn 50 reputation so that you can leave comments on other people's posts.

Until that happens, please use answers only for answering the question, not asking for clarifications or any other purpose.